# Custom implementation of tf.gather in Graph mode

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I need to write a custom implementation of tf.gather with basic tensor flow operations. I can not use the standard tf.gather implementation provided by tensorflow 2.2.0 and can't upgrade my tensorflow version. It is required that the implementation work in graph mode because my model needs to be converted to .tflite.

Some of the basic tensorflow operations that I can use are: add, concat, fill, mul, split, strided_slice, sub and unpack.

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you combined slices of tensors or work on similar sequences.

Sample: Re-scaling and logarithms scale pictures.

New way of information collection to simple sense as our commons smiles.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
None
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
print(physical_devices)
print(config)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
start = 0
limit = 20
delta = 10

log_scales_height = 288
log_scales_width = 144

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
Working
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
IMAGE_1 = plt.imread("F:\\Pictures\\actor-Ploy\\7-5.jpg")
IMAGE_1 = tf.image.resize(IMAGE_1, [log_scales_height, log_scales_width]).numpy()
IMAGE_1 = tf.constant( IMAGE_1, dtype=tf.int32 ).numpy()

params = plt.imread("F:\\Pictures\\actor-Ploy\\7-5.jpg")
params = tf.image.resize(params, [600, 300])
params = tf.reshape( params, ( params.shape[0] * params.shape[1], 3 ))

limit = tf.math.divide( params.shape[0] * params.shape[1], delta, name='Devide' ).numpy()
limit = 180000

indices = tf.range(start, limit, delta)
result = tf.gather(params, indices)     
result = tf.reshape( result, (150, 120, 3) )
result = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(
        result,
        data_format=None,
        scale=True
    )

plt.figure(figsize=(1,2))
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
plt.grid(False)
plt.imshow(IMAGE_1)
plt.xlabel(" rescaling ")

plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
plt.grid(False)
plt.imshow(result)
plt.xlabel(" logarithms pictires ")

plt.show()
input('...')
```

[image: Sample]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this answer the question since you are still using tf.gather to collect your logarithms pictures. Are you using tf.gather just to show that it works and it can be done somehow with tf.range ?

Comment: I example of how we use it, you can create pixels and boundaries collection for calculation such none symmetric shapes see her cheeks.